# VBA - Sub that calls functions that call other fucntions

Tags: vba, excel

It's been a couple years since I learned a bit of VBA and I'm definitely rusty.

I'm trying to define the variables in a Sub, and then from that Sub, call various functions, some of the functions will call other functions and so on.

So far the code is as follows:

```
'AREAS

Public Sub Areas()

Dim h, btf, bbf, tw, ttf, tbf As Double

h = 300
btf = 150
bbf = 150
tw = 7.1
tbf = 10.7
ttf = 10.7

Call TotalArea(h, btf, bbf, tw, ttf, tbf)
Call Sum_of_Areas(h, btf, bbf, tw, ttf, tbf)

End Sub


Function TotalArea(h, btf, bbf, tw, ttf, tbf As Double) As Double

TotalArea = btf * ttf + bbf * tbf + (h - ttf - tbf) * tw

End Function

Function Area_tf(btf, ttf As Double) As Double

Area_tf = btf * ttf

End Function

Function Area_bf(bbf, tbf As Double) As Double

Area_bf = bbf * tbf

End Function

Function Area_w(h, ttf, tbf, tw As Double) As Double

Area_w = (h - ttf - tbf) * tw

End Function

Function Sum_of_Areas(h, btf, bbf, tw, ttf, tbf As Double) As Double

Sum_of_Areas = Area_tf + Area_bf + Area_w

End Function
```

The first bit runs fine, i.e. the TotalArea function, but the other (the Sum_of_Areas) just gives me errors. I'm trying to find what the appropriate way of doing this would be and what variables do I need to declare and where. And which variables I need to pass to the functions.

Thanks!

Comment: You have to pass every parameter to a function (or sub) that is not optional. So `Area_tf + Area_bf + Area_w` in `Sum_of_Areas` are missing their parameters! Keep in mind that `Dim h, btf, bbf, tw, ttf, tbf As Double`only declares `tbf`as `Double`, the others are type `Variant`. No error messages?

Answer (score 1):

You must use same type variable of sub and function .
And do not call for function.

```
Public Sub Areas()

Dim h As Double, btf As Double, bbf As Double, tw As Double, ttf As Double, tbf As Double
Dim Total As Double, mySum As Double
h = 300
btf = 150
bbf = 150
tw = 7.1
tbf = 10.7
ttf = 10.7

Total = TotalArea(h, btf, bbf, tw, ttf, tbf)
mySum = Sum_of_Areas(h, btf, bbf, tw, ttf, tbf)
Range("a1") = Total
Range("a2") = mySum
End Sub


Function TotalArea(h As Double, btf As Double, bbf As Double, tw As Double, ttf As Double, tbf As Double) As Double

TotalArea = btf * ttf + bbf * tbf + (h - ttf - tbf) * tw

End Function

Function Area_tf(btf As Double, ttf As Double) As Double

Area_tf = btf * ttf

End Function

Function Area_bf(bbf As Double, tbf As Double) As Double

Area_bf = bbf * tbf

End Function

Function Area_w(h, ttf, tbf, tw As Double) As Double

Area_w = (h - ttf - tbf) * tw

End Function

Function Sum_of_Areas(h As Double, btf As Double, bbf As Double, tw As Double, ttf As Double, tbf As Double) As Double

'Sum_of_Areas = Area_tf + Area_bf + Area_w
Sum_of_Areas = Area_tf(btf, ttf) + Area_bf(bbf, tbf) + Area_w(h, ttf, tbf, tw)

End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for that guys!

I'll try to organize as much as possible, declare all the variables only once in a sub and from there call the functions I need. Is that the proper way to proceed with this?

Buy, it's probably going to get a bit daunting once I start adding more stuff. Is there any way I can make it easier with pyhton? Like have all the processing in python and just send variables from vba to python a get other variables (results) back?

Comment: @Miguel, It depends on how your data structure is.

Comment: My idea is to have a userform where the user inputs some numbers. Then do a bunch of processing with those numbers (basically checking against a Civil Engineering Code) and finally give the user some more numbers back after all the processing. Would python be usefull? And if so, would the user have to have python installed in its machine?

Comment: My view is, Yes it would be quite possible to use Excel as a simple front end and do all the calculations in Python but why?  There would have to be a very strong reason why I would do it that way and I can't see any such reason in your explanation of your project. The type of calculations you are doing is bread and butter stuff for excel it is what it was designed to do and will do it very simply and Efficiently. By structuring your code properly put the right indentations on it and plenty of comments you can make it pretty straight forwards This is just my view but hope it helps. .